# How to provide gap between two separate structure or microstrip lines in ADS(Advanced design systems)?

Tags: microwave, microstrip, ads, resonator

I want to provide gap between two resonators. Here is an image. How do I provide those gap M12 and M23.
[image]

Comment: Look for the coupled microstrip components.

Comment: Is there any other way? Because in some cases it is not possible to use coupled lines.

Comment: Where is it not possible to use coupled lines?

Comment: If you have a license for the multilayer components library, you can model [coupled corners](http://literature.cdn.keysight.com/litweb/pdf/ads2005a/ccdist/index.html).